# Delete div with same class except one

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs like the following

```
<div class="FixedHeader_Cloned fixedHeader FixedHeader_Header">
  ...
</div>
```

I want to keep 1 of the divs and delete the other ones. How can I achieve this using jquery? I tried doing this with the following code, but I don't know how to go from here to actually delete the elements I want to delete.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var count = 0;
    $(".FixedHeader_Cloned").each(function()
    {
        count++;
    });
    for(i=1; i<count; i++)
    {
      // iterate through one by one and delete them like an element from array
    }

});
```

Comment: Which div you want to keep? I mean 1s or 2nd  3rd 4th. which one you want to keep?

Comment: `$(".FixedHeader_Cloned:lt(3)").remove()` etc, there are like thirty jQuery methods to refine a selection.

Comment: Downvoted for persistent insulting in your question edits. Not only is this disruptive, but it creates editing work, and you are liable to be suspended for it.

Comment: Why the downvote now??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".FixedHeader_Cloned").not(':last-child').remove();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/foaneLjm/)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('.FixedHeader_Cloned:not(:last-child)').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".FixedHeader_Cloned").each(function(i, e) {
    if (i > 0) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rogeriolino/3xfszqw5/

Comment: With the loop you can easily remove elements on complex index or situation. So, just one more alternative.